# Asking Panamanian immigration for souvenir stamp outside of passport

Tags: passport-stamps

I will be traveling to Panama shortly. In Germany, where I am from, all kids know the [Tigerente](https://www.janosch-shop.com/1117/holz-tigerente-mit-schnur-das-original-die-janosch-holz-tigerente-mit-schnur-zum-hinterherziehen-zertifiziertes-holz-kinderspiel.jpg) (tiger duck), who traveled to [Panama](https://www.finews.ch/images/cache/1904c83c1048a6c2b7ac58be2f75dfa4_w500_h300_cp.jpg).

I am considering buying/building such a wooden toy and asking at immigration to have it stamped.

<s>Is this a reasonable thing to do?</s> In my mind, the worst that could happen is a stern Are-you-serious-look, but I thought I should ask for a second opinion on this.

Comment: Bonus question: Does anyone have an idea what type of wood finishing would be best suited to hold the stamp? ;)

Comment: Rather than asking an official to use an official stamp for a clearly non-official purpose, which seems iffy, why not just purchase some postage stamps and affix them? It's authentic and inexpensive and you can find one that's official-looking.

Answer (score 1):

Not a good idea in non-EU/EFTA countries, as they can refuse you entry for any reason they like, and a grumpy officer may perceive your odd wish as suspicious behaviour.

**Much** better to ask for a German stamp - the *Bundespolizei* can hardly do much more than say no. I collect stamps on a blank sheet when in the mood (I use a Swedish ID card) and the Germans have always given me one when asked.